# Unable to align multi-line text to middle of a container

Tags: html, css

I'm new to css, so I not getting the way to make the text center of a container (div).

My HTML is

```
<div class="container">Some text goes over here.</div>
```

I tried with `text-align: center`, and `vertical-align: middle`, but no luck.

Is there any way we could make the text align in the center of the Div.

Comment: You can use "display: table-cell" along with "vertical-align: middle"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `display: table-cell` and the `vertical-align: middle` to set you text at the middle of the container.

```
.divClass {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 2px solid red;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      display: table-cell;
}
```

Check the working over here. http://jsfiddle.net/32rD7/

Comment: Thanks for the answer i'll give this a try. Just for my info, will this work in IE9 & IE10?

Comment: No for IE9 but not sure about IE10. If you want the support for them, please have a look at this. http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `Text-Align:center;`

```
 <div class="container" style="Text-Align:center;">Some text goes over here.</div>
```

Comment: OP already tried that, also I think OP want horizontal and Vertical centering

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel like applying various CSS hacks, you could take a look at the (experimental) [flexbox layout](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/).

```
div.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Note that I omitted vendor prefixes.

Comment: Nice one. Will give this a try.